# VkKeyScan возвращает значение текущей раскладки клавиатуры

Tags: c++

Подскажите почему send_key('Q') сработает только если у меня включена раскладка английского языка? Подскажите как исправить сделать так чтобы независимо от раскладки посылалось 'Q'

```
void send_key(char key)
{
    byte vk = VkKeyScan(key);
    unsigned short sc = MapVirtualKey(vk, 0);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, vk, sc << 16 | 1);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, vk, sc << 16 | 1);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, vk, sc << 1 << 31 | 1 << 30 | sc << 16 | 1);
}
```

Comment: Ты в курсе, что `sc << 16 | 1` - это `sc << 17`? Подозреваю, что надо добавить скобки.

Comment: Уже пишу развёрнутый ответ про необходимость использования `VkKeyScanEx`. @Qwertiy, тут, похоже, наложение двух ошибок — указанной вами и неверный выбор функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `VkKeyScan()` ищет соответствие символа виртуальной клавише только в текущей раскладке:

> Translates a character to the corresponding virtual-key code and shift state **for the current keyboard**.

Это сделано во избежание неоднозначностей — один и тот же символ может встречаться в разных раскладках на разных клавишах (например, в QWERTY и Dvorak).

Поэтому вам необходима функция `VkKeyScanEx()`, которая позволяет явно указать интересующую вас раскладку. В примере ниже я жёстко привяжусь к раскладке QWERTY. Однако вам надо будет решить вопрос возможного наличия у пользователя других англоязычных раскладок (иногда даже при отсутствующем QWERTY).

1. Загружаем раскладку, чтобы получить её дескриптор. Это можно сделать в начале работы программы, при получении первого `WM_SETFOCUS` (ограничение Windows 8 и выше)

   ```
   const HKL hklQwerty = LoadKeyboardLayout(
       MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US),
       KLF_SUBSTITUTE_OK
   );
   ```
2. Соответственно, получение кода нажатой клавиши примет следующий вид:

   ```
   byte vk = VkKeyScanEx(key, hklQwerty);
   ```
3. При закрытии программы необходимо освободить дескриптор раскладки (т. к. это не ядерный `HANDLE`, а потому не факт, что он будет освобождён автоматически при закрытии программы):

   ```
   UnloadKeyboardLayout(hklQwerty);
   ```

Comment: Ядерный или не ядерный? А то что-то подозрительно фраза выглядит.